# Problems with characters to display

Tags: android, character

I have a problem with the display of characters.

I have a CSV file which are written the symbol of the currencies used in some countries.

When I try to display the symbol of the British pound, on some devices is displayed correctly, while on others is not displayed correctly.

Why this happens? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be a encoding problem.

You can change the encoding of a file with right click / properties / Resource and changing the text file encodign (try ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8).

After changing the encoding if all characters are not displayed well try to change manually :)

Hope this helps...

Comment: It does not work, because I do not think that is a problem of encoding

Answer (score 0):

```
Spanned spannded = Html.fromHtml("&pound;");
        String pound = spannded.toString();
```

Comment: I discovered that the problem may be a custom font, which I absolutely have to use.

The font does not specify the character of British pound, but on some devices it seems that some mechanism comes into play on other devices, the default font is not recognized.

Comment: Where you want to display pound symbol use the above code there. It will work irrespective of device config